# Javascript using filter/includes on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to filter out data that exists within an object?

I was able to do use the below code when `data` was just an array of values but now I need to `filter` out any data where the `item.QID` exists in my array of objects.

**Data Obj:**

```
var data = [{
  QID: 'ABC123',
  Name: 'Joe'
},
{
 QID: 'DEF456',
 Name: 'Bob
}]
```

**Snippet:**

```
// I don't want to include data if this QID is in my object
this.employees = emp.filter(item =>!this.data.includes(item.QID));
```

From what I understand, `includes` only works on an array so I need to treat all of the `QID` values in my object as an array.

**Desired Outcome:** (assuming `item.QID = ABC123`)

```
this.employees = emp.filter(item =>!this.data.includes('ABC123'));
```

**Result:**

```
var data = [{
  QID: 'DEF456',
  Name: 'Bob'
}]
```

**UPDATE:**
Apologies, I left some things a little unclear trying to only include the necessary stuff.

```
// People Search
    this.peopleSearchSub = this.typeahead
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debounceTime(200)
        .switchMap(term => this._mapsService.loadEmployees(term))
        .subscribe(emp => {
            // Exclude all of the current owners
            this.employees = emp.filter((item) => item.QID !== this.data.QID);
        }, (err) => {
            this.employees = [];
        });
```

The above code is what I am working with. `data` is an object of users I want to exclude from my type-ahead results by filtering them out.

Comment: Where is `emp` defined?

Comment: @guest271314- I added a little more context around what I left out

Answer (score 5):

The question is a little ambiguous, but my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong), is that you want to remove all items from a list `emp` that have the same QID as any item in another list `data`?

If that's the case, try:

```
this.employees = emp.filter(item => !this.data.some(d => d.QID === item.QID))
```

some is an array method that returns true if it's callback is true for any of the arrays elements. So in this case, `some(d => d.QID === item.QID)` would be true if ANY of the elements of the list `data` have the same QID as `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Object#hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
this.employees = emp.filter(item =>item.hasOwnProperty('QID'));
```

Comment: OP is checking for a specific value at the property

Comment: @guest271314 not what is stated.... *" any data where the item.QID exists"*. Might be mis-worded ... was my interpretation anyway

Comment: Granted, though see next line _"Desired Outcome: (assuming `item.QID = ABC123`)"_ and expected result

Comment: yeah...question is ambiguous

Comment: Another issue with Question is where `emp` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for ... in to loop through and filter out what you want:

```
const data = [{
    QID: 'ABC123',
    Name: 'Joe'
},
 {
   QID: 'DEF456',
   Name: 'Bob'
 }]

let newData     = [];
let filterValue = 'ABC123';

for (let value in data) {
  if (data[value].QID !== filterValue) {
    newData.push(data[value]);
  }
}
```

`newData` will be your new filtered array in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use an es6 .filter for that. I also added a couple of elements showing the filtered list and an input to allow changing of the filtered value. This list will update on the click of the button.

```js
const data = [{
    QID: 'ABC123',
    Name: 'Joe'
},
 {
   QID: 'DEF456',
   Name: 'Bob'
 }]

displayData(data);

function displayData(arr) {
  let str = '';
  document.getElementById('filterList').innerHTML = '';

  arr.forEach((i) => { str += "<li>" + i.QID + ": " + i.Name + "</li>"})
  document.getElementById('filterList').innerHTML = str;
}

function filterData() {
let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value;
filterText (filterValue);
}


function filterText (filterValue) {
  let newArr = data.filter((n) => n.QID !== filterValue); 
  displayData(newArr)
}
```

```html
<input id="filterInput" type="text" value="ABC123" />
<button type ="button" onclick="filterData()">Filter</button>
<hr/>
<ul id="filterList"><ul>
```